# Reading a string, printing a name and adding integers

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

so I am to write a method through Java that will read a file input, print a string that is a name, and sum up golf scores. I am literally stumped and can not think of how to do this. I have a main method that has been given and is not to be altered. This leaves me with another method to do all the work. Thus far I have,

```
public static void computeScores(Scanner file) {
    int numGolfers = file.nextInt();

    // add your code here

    int highScore;
    int totalScore = 0;
    boolean beatPar;
    beatPar = totalScore <= 72; 

    System.out.print("Number of golfers: " + numGolfers + "\n\n");
    System.out.println("NAME   SCORE   TO PAR");
    System.out.println("----   -----   ------");

    for (int i = 1; i <= numGolfers; i++) {

        String golferName = file.next();



        boolean isLineOver = golferName == "\n";
        while (isLineOver) {
            int score = file.nextInt();
            if () {
            totalScore += score;
        }
            System.out.print(totalScore);
        }

         String nextGolfer = file.nextLine();  
         System.out.println(golferName + "    " + totalScore);

        //System.out.println(nextGolfer);

    }
    if (beatPar) {
        System.out.println("At least one golfer scored par or below.");
    }

}
```

I have only been able to output the names, and sometimes the first number from a list of 18 numbers. Sorry about the extraneous code that's been commented out.

Any kind of pointers would be appreciated.

The file I have been given has information in the following format

Name 1 2 3 4 5 etc.

Comment: Try to replace the `while (isLineOver) {` with `while (golferName.equals("\n")) {`. For string comparison you need to use `.equals` and also in your while loop you are not setting a new value to the `isLineOver`.

Answer (score 0):

change `golferName == "\n"` to `golferName.equals("\n")` for Strings

Comment: I appreciate the help guys, but i'm still relatively new to java and some of the things you have shown me have not been discussed in class yet. I'm trying to complete my assignment within the confines of what we have learned. Thus far, I have updated my code and cleaned it up a bit.

Comment: Instead of boolean var - isLineOver. You can use hasNextInt() method of Scanner class.